# Are Feynman diagrams equivalent when gluons are emitted from different quarks?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, strong-force, gluons

3rd year physics undergrad here. I am new to particle physics.

We were asked to give the lowest order Feynman diagram of this reaction.

$$K_1^+(1400) \to K^+ \pi^+\pi^- $$

Now I came up with not one but two possible diagrams.

The only difference is that the two gluons are emitted from the different quarks. See Below.

**Are they equivalent ?**

Is one more conventional or likely ?

Shall I give both as an answer ?

[image: reaction 1]

**No 1:** found this given somewhere

[image: reaction 2]

**No 2:** came up with this

Also as a side-note what does the subscript of the Kaon in the first reaction mean ?

I would appreciate any help on this!

Thank you in advance,

Kindest Regards,

Gordon

Comment: Title question is interesting. However, the decay $K^-\to\mu\nu$ is a weak process, while your gluon diagrams are all purely strong decays. Did you mean to ask about $K\to\pi\pi K$?

Comment: Oh, yeah ... sorry I put the wrong reaction picture.. Your suggestion was indeed what I meant. Changed the question now. Thank you.